# Adjust shape size in cytoscape.js with dagre layout

Tags: javascript, layout, graph, cytoscape.js, dagre

I am trying to resize the shapes of the nodes to the size of the node text. I followed instructions from https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/649 . However:

1. The shapes always end up with height = width
2. The size of all shapes is the same.
3. The shape size seems to reach a max above which it can't grow.

(I am not sure if this has something to do with dagre layout.)

I am using the following libraries with the dagre layout:

- `cytoscape.min.js`
- `dagre.min.js`
- `cytoscape-dagre.js`

  ```
  container: document.getElementById('cy'),
  boxSelectionEnabled: false, autounselectify: true,

  layout: {name: 'dagre', rankDir: 'LR', align: 'LR'},

  style: [{
      selector: 'node',
      style: {
          'content': 'data(name)',
          'label': 'data(name)',
          'text-opacity': 1,
          'text-valign': 'center',
          'text-halign': 'center',
          'text-wrap': 'wrap',
          'font-size': 9,
          'background-color': '#AAA',
          'shape':'rectangle',
          'width': 'data(width)' * 50,
          'height': 'data(height)' * 50 }
  },{
      selector: 'edge',
      style: {
          'width': 4,
          'content': 'data(name)',
          'target-arrow-shape': 'triangle',
          'line-color': 'data(color)',
          'text-wrap': 'wrap',
          'target-arrow-color': 'data(color)',
          'font-size': 10,
      }
  }]
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You've specified invalid style.  `"somestring" * 50` is `NaN`.

You want `width: label`, as indicated in the docs: http://js.cytoscape.org/#style/node-body

Comment: Thanks Max. It works now. I was searching this site but somehow overlooked that section. This helps a lot. Thanks again.

Comment: That property is deprecated: "The style value of `label` is deprecated for `width`"